# max value from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary look like

```
dic = {
   "X": 15, 
   "Y": 20, 
   "Z": 2 
}
```

and i will add to each values the minimum value of my dictionary. And I write this code

```
minimum = min(list(dic.values()))
dic["X"] = dic["X"] + minimum 
dic["Y"] = dic["Y"] + minimum 
dic["Z"] = dic["Z"] + minimum
```

required result

```
{ "X": 17, "Y": 22, "Z": 4 }
```

My code works, but i think it's noto so good solution. Somebody heve better solution than me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dic = {
   "X": 15, 
   "Y": 20, 
   "Z": 2 
}
minimum = min(dic.values())
for key in dic:
    dic[key] += minimum
print(dic)
```

out:

```
{'X': 17, 'Z': 4, 'Y': 22}
```

how to use min():

```
min(iterable, *[, key, default ])
min(arg1, arg2, *args[, key ])
```

> If one positional argument is provided, it should be an **iterable**. The
>   smallest item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional
>   arguments are provided, the smallest of the positional arguments is
>   returned.

`dic[key] = value` is a in-place change, no need to produce a new dict container.

Answer (score 1):

or using a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
minimum = min(dic.values())

dic2 = {x: val + minimum for x, val in dic.items()}
```

note: for the `min` you do not need to `list` the values; this only creates an unnecessary list.